# How to replace the last character in a file with sed without knowing that character

Tags: sed

I want to replace the last character in a file.

1. I don't know what that character is.
2. I just know its position: The end of the file.

Let's generate a file via `echo -n -e '1234\n5X78\nX' >> test.file` which gives.

```
$ cat test.file
1234
5X78
X
```

There is no newline in the last line.

I know how to replace the last character when I know it is `X`.

```
sed '$s/X/0/' test.file
1234
5X78
0
```

But as I said I don't know the last character.

Comment: The last character in a text file is a newline character, the delimiter of the last line. In your case, it's added by `echo` which always adds one unless you use the `-n` option (with some implementations), or add a `\c` (with others, the standard ones, not the case of yours which seems to supports that non-standard `-e`). You probably meant *"how to remove the last character of the last line of the file"*. Then there's the question of what to do if that line is empty.

Comment: re: your edit, note that a file that doesn't end in a newline character, by definition is not a text file, so can't be processed POSIXly with text utilities such as `sed`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using sed :

```
sed 's/.$/0/' test.file
```

The `.` define any character, and `$` is the end of the line.
So you will replace any last character of each line by `0` in this example.

```
sed '$s/.$/0/' test.file
```

Adding a `$` before the action you have to do will only apply the action to the last line.

Answer (score 3):

This is simple, just use `.$`:

```
sed '$s/.$/0/' test.file
```

- `.` is "any" character.
- `$` is the end of the line.

So, you will replace the last character at the end of the last line.